# Como quitar K2BTOOLS en Genexus

Tags: genexus

Por favor alguien que me ayude! Hace dias le agregue k2btools (te hace una interfaz diferente) en mi proyecto de genexus pero ahora quiero desactivarlo o quitarlo que ya no aparezca con los diseños de allí, alguien sabe que tengo que hacer?...

Answer (score 1):

En una Transaction en la opción "Patterns" vas a ver 3 pestañas que corresponden a K2BTools.

- Entity Services (WorkWhit)
- Prompt
- TrnForm

Cada una tiene la opción "Apply this pattern on save" . Desactiva el tilde de la pestaña que necesites y guarda el objeto. De esa forma estas quitando k2btools,para esa opción en particular, del objeto en el que estas trabajando.